# Adding and displaying variables in a list

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a score calculator, when you input a score between 1 and 100 it stores it, shows the count of how many scores have been entered and what the average is. We're supposed to have it add the data using List< int> and display using foreach in a message box. I have tried multiple different ways to add and display the data. When I do scores.Add(whatever) and try to call it in the click action for "Display" it just shows a system message however many times you've entered in. I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
int Count = 0;
decimal Total = 0m;
List<int> scores = new List<int>();

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Score = Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text);
    scores.Add(1);

    Total += Score;
    Count++;

    decimal Average = Total / Count;

    txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
    txtCount.Text = Count.ToString();
    txtAverage.Text = Average.ToString();
    txtScore.Focus();
}

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Count = 0;
    decimal Total = 0m;
    decimal Average = 0m;
    int Score = 0;

    scores.Clear();
    txtScore.Text = Score.ToString();
    txtAverage.Text = Average.ToString();
    txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
    txtCount.Text = Count.ToString();
}

private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (int scoring in scores)                       
}
```

I've tried looking at the examples in my book and on here but they're all for string. This is about as far into my code as I'm able to get. I am so stuck!

Comment: Are you supposed to display each score in a **different** message box?...or use a for loop to iterate over all of them, adding them to a string as you go, then display all of them at once in ONE message box?

Comment: I don't see where you check if the input is a number between 1 and 100

Comment: You are also doing `scores.Add(1)` instead of `scores.Add(Score)`. Is that intentional?

Comment: *"it just shows a system message"* What does the message say? That might be a good clue...

Comment: Please fill in the `foreach` with the code that's not working so we can help correct where it went wrong. Are you trying to build a string with all the values (like, "You entered: 1, 2, 3") or show a separate message box for each score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables 'Total' and 'Count' are basically useless. Try this:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    scores.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtScore.Text));
    txtTotal.Text = scores.Sum()+"";
    txtCount.Text = scores.Count()+"";
    txtAverage.Text = scores.Average()+"";
    txtScore.Focus();
}
```

And then, in the clear button:

```
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    scores.Clear();
    txtScore.Text = 0+"";
    txtAverage.Text = 0+"";
    txtTotal.Text = 0+"";
    txtCount.Text = 0+"";
}
```

In the display button:

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string message = "";
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var score in scores)  {
         message += $"[{index++}]: {score}\n";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Comment: Why do you concatenate an empty string to everything, like `0+""`? Why not `"0"`?

Comment: Its a way of forcing the `ToString()` method to be called without actually referencing it.

Comment: I know, I was just curious if there was a reason - I haven't seen that pattern before (unless the appended string has a value, of course). Does this incur boxing in the underlying call to Concat?

Comment: I believe so. But is just force of habit. I could use "0" and this is probably more efficient. However, I usually have a variable and instead of using `ToString()` i use +""; for short.

Comment: This was very very helpful! The only thing is it needs to display in only one message box as a list of variables.

Comment: you mean each of the elements of the list in one messagebox?

Comment: exactly, Vinicius.

Comment: @ViníciusGabriel I was finally able to get it to work right private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            
            
            txtScore.Text = 0+"";
            txtAverage.Text = 0+"";
            txtTotal.Text = 0+"";
            txtCount.Text = 0+"";
            
            scores.Clear();

scores.Clear();  is not clearing the list at all.

Comment: are you sure about that? check if scores.Count is zero in a messagebox after the Clear(). If indeed, for some reason, the list is not being cleared, try creating the list again: scores = new List<int>();